# AWS VPC through a higher level PaaS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, amazon-vpc

I have been using Heroku up to now, but need to offer something more "enterprise-y" to an organisation that would otherwise insist on local server deployment.

AWS VPC sounds like the ideal infrastructure to use. I'll have Rails + Postgres + AWS S3.

Maybe a silly questions, but is there an automated PaaS that runs on top of AWS? Such that we own the AWS account but can outsource the server admin side? Or is this just a case of having to hire a consultant and deal with upgrades etc. as they arise?

Comment: Was there a question in there? It sounds like you are saying "I want to do something, but I want someone else to do it". Please clarify you actual question, or hire a consultant.

Comment: Fair enough, reworded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there an automated PaaS that runs on top of AWS?

Yes, there are **LOTS** of them. They range in spectrum from "a thin layer on Elastic BeanStalk" to wanna-be Heroku clones.  (From my experience, most don't think about HA enough, so it works great, but has plenty of Single Points of Failure that can bite you down the road. But maybe you don't need so many nines of availability at first. Anyone remember Twitter in the early days?)

There are plenty of points in between, such as EC2 Containers, OpsWorks, Flynn, CoreOS, etc.  Even [Empire](http://engineering.remind.com/introducing-empire/) which I haven't looked at yet.

Every PaaS is a "Straitjacket" that reduces your "freedom to do anything" in exchange for "simplifying some things".  That trade-off is not a constant, nor universal.

A PaaS that works for one company may not work for another, or even the same company six months later. I frequently see companies use Heroku or Google AppEngine for months/years, then suddenly hit a wall and need move off of it. After, they wonder why they put up with the limitations for so long.

> we own the AWS account but can outsource the server admin side?

Yes, you can easily pay someone to setup a "PaaS" for you. The problem is they have to have a *lot* of knowledge to know which one will work best. (Few people have tried them all and talk intelligently about the trade-offs between them all. And new ones get written practically every day.)

The one universal thing: Companies rarely outgrow AWS. (Remember Zynga? They thought they were "spending too much money" on AWS, so they built their own datacenter. It supposedly "saved them money" until their fortunes turned around. Then that datacenter became a boat anchor that pulled them under. Ooops.)

> Or is this just a case of having to hire a consultant and deal with upgrades etc. as they arise?

You need to think *deeply* about what it is that you want.

You could stay high level and run on a 3rd party PaaS. There are no shortage of them (Engine Yard, Heroku, etc). You trade a bit of extra money now (and it's really a few bucks per month) for speed. But you pay a cost later when you have to move off. That's OK, as long as it bought you some time to prove your business model, get customers, etc.

You could hire a consultant to build you a PaaS on AWS. (Why? Is it merely to save money? To gain flexibility? How will you know they are competent? How do you know they aren't a one-trick pony building the same solution they built for everybody else, without knowing where it will work and not work?)

You could bite the bullet and hire (or grow) a cloud guy. They learn AWS and iterate. This will give you the most flexibility in the future. You will be prepared to take advantage of cost savings offered by tuning your application to AWS. (A generic PaaS doesn't encourage you do to this, which means you will loose out of performance or cost savings.)

Long term, I think only the last one makes sense. The 3rd party PaaS is also a fine way to gain speed in the short-term.  I'm not so keen on a consultant, unless it's to help accelerate knowledge transfer to your company.

Comment: Thanks. Time to the initial release is an issue, so I'm hoping for something (nearly) as easy as Heroku but with the result being I control the AWS resources, allowing me to skill up and hire in over time. AWS OpsWorks looks good but still needs a custom recipe for Postgres and I don't know what else.. It looks like I may need a consultant to set up AWS VPC with Rails app to start.